# JQuery Datepicker Returning Empty on One Form But Not Others

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Having a problem with the datepicker: when I click on a date, the datepicker works as it should but the form field empties itself of even any current content and remains empty until reloaded or a new entry is selected.

Before this stopped working and only on this one form, all the work I had been doing was elsewhere on the site and in PHP rather than Javascript so I don't even know where to begin and nothing shows in the Apache logs either. There is no other Javascript on this page so what I need to know is how to check for conflicts when there are no errors.

Just to be sure that the code itself looks okay, here it is:

The Javascript that is in an external js file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $( "#StartDate" ).datepicker({ 
                        altField: '#datepicker',
                        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        dateFormat: 'D M d, yy', 
                        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#StartDate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker({
                        altField: '#datepicker',
                        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        dateFormat: 'D M d, yy', 
                        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#EndDate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    }); 
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                        altField: '#datepicker',
                        altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                        dateFormat: 'D M d, yy', 
                        firstDay: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    }); 
});
```

The form field itself:

```
<input type="text" name="EventDate" value="Fri Jan 11, 2019" size="15" id="datepicker">
```

. . .and the form is having issues with the one called ***datepicker***. The other two are working prefectly on another form which has two datepickers.

Comment: why not use a class instead?

Comment: Class for what? I know nothing about Javascript so more detail is appreciated, especially as the datepicker itself is working but not populating this form even though other forms on the same site are working using the same code.

Comment: instead of using an ID for each you can use a CSS Class to select them all, so instead of 3 datepicker code you can do One,  Typically.

Comment: This form is using only the one named datepicker and that is the one causing the problem (the other two are for one special form that has two datepickers and I don't think that changing to class would make those work with only a single one, would it?). However, perhaps the original post wasn't clear that the main question here isn't about the code (unless something is glaringly wrong) but rather about how to determine what **else** might be interfering with it when there are no errors being generated. The datepicker itself is working just fine but the form is left blank after selecting a date.

Comment: Narrowed the problem down to the last onClose which when remarked out the datepicker works. However, with it remarked out, another page that had been working no longer does. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the problem in my original question was something in the OnLoad bits and with it removed from the last section that wasn't working, it worked but then the other two did not so removing all of them it worked fine. There must be some syntax error or other in it.

In any event, it is now fixed properly. Once I realized what @ArtisticPhoenix meant by class I was able to implement it to simplify the code considerably and to make it work with any form no matter how many datepickers they may have. I now have this:

```
$(function() {
   $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
    altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', 
    firstDay: 1
   });
});
```

The form itself in this case is semi-dynamic, meaning that it's created from an array of values found in a definition function so simply changing the definition was all that was needed to make it work properly throughout several sites. Now the id is simply the field name and class is always datepicker. Seems to work perfectly so far!

```
<input type="text" name="EventDate" value="2019-01-11" size="15" id="EventDate" class="datepicker">
```